# Printing on Windows 8 with PDF viewer (Adobe Reader) from network

Tags: networking, windows-8, pdf, printing, adobe-reader

i have a problem with the Adobe Reader 8, but the problem seems to be equally bad with other pdf viewers.
Here is the configuration:
**My PDF viewer is located on network drive "Z:" which is the network adress \dgs-main\progs.**

I tried to start the adobe reader from here -> *\\dgs-main\progs\Adobe\Reader 8.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe*
and open the PDF from here -> *C:\Users\ServiceDesk\AppData\Local\Temp\GeneratedPDF.pdf*

The problem is as follows, if i open the PDF with a local PDF viewer everything works fine and i can print the document.
If i open the PDF with the Network PDF viewer then it opens, but printing is impossible.
The error message states: "**Unable to start print job. Is printer available?**"

As mentioned above, it works with a local pdf viewer.
In both cases i use the same printer.
The Printer is a network printer but even with a local printer it fails.

**The error occurs only on Windows 8 machines**. 
On windows 7 it works fine.

I Hope somebody can tell me what the problem is.
Thanks in advance and have a fine day.

Comment: How is the printer configured?  Are you sure the remote server with Adobe Reader is aware of the printe?

Comment: Yes the Server on which the PDF Viewer lies is aware of the printer. Should this be the issue ? because i start the Adobe Reader on my machine